# Haskell Enum Comparison

Tags: haskell, enums

I've defined an enum:

```
data Direction = Clockwise | CounterClockwise deriving (Enum)
```

Variable 'direction' has type 'Direction'. When doing the following comparison:

```
direction == Clockwise
```

I'm getting this error:

```
  No instance for (Eq OrbitDirection) arising from a use of `=='
  In the expression: direction == Clockwise
```

Comment: Pretty much any *exported* `Enum` should also derive `Eq`, `Ord`, `Show`, and `Read`. At some point, you may want to add `Generic` to that list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is as simple as it gets: add the `Eq` instance to the derived instances list:

```
data Direction = Clockwise | CounterClockwise deriving (Enum, Eq)
```